# Ошибка при подключении компонента

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем Привет.
У меня такая проблема:
Прохожу курс на Удеми по Vue.js и столкнулся с тем, что аналогичный пример(подключения компонента) на курсе работает, а в моем случае нет.
Что я упускаю из вида?

[Ссылка на Github](https://github.com/Mike-Kharkov/vue/tree/636dd1c658295506af2ec4b5e7e7fd3121ed8685)

Подозреваю что это могут быть проблемы связанные с фичами Vue.js, такими как Vue Loader - но я устанавливал последние версии всего, что только можно..

Буду благодарен за любую помощь..

[image: вот так код выглядит в редакторе:]

Comment: "не работает" - это какая ошибка/какое поведение?

Comment: Открывается пустая страница.
В фаербаге не наблюдается внутренних тегов кроме самого глобального.
IDE выдает предупреждение, которое видно (в самом низу) на 1-м скриншоте..
+
после подключения вот это строки:
[http://joxi.ru/vAWWbPKIkbqV7A](http://joxi.ru/vAWWbPKIkbqV7A)
Все проблемы и появляются..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Компонент объявляется с помощью `Vue.component`, а не `Vue.Component` (внимание на регистр). Если у вас действительно нет ошибок в консоли, вероятно, что это не единственная проблема.